# runtime error : asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio

This is a code I created recently for my first discord project
this code is supposed to send messages automatically

```py
import discord, time, os, random ,asyncio

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def bt(self):
        print("Logged on as {0}!".format(self.user()))
        channel = client.get_channel(932867446723989524)
        while True:
            for i in range(1,25):
                await channel.send("hi")
                asyncio.sleep(20)
                await channel.send("hello")
                asyncio.sleep(random.randint(2,17))
                for a in range(1,11):
                    await channel.send("anyone there")
                    asyncio.sleep(random.randint(601,700))
client =  discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
token ="mytoken"
print("ACTIVE WORKING NOW")                                                                                        
client.run(token)
```

this had worked in repl.it but not in my local laptop(using vscode)
it gives a error saying `runtimeerror:asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop`
I have used another version of it and it gives `<coroutine object client.start at 0x0....`
the code i used for that used client.start instead of client.run
I am using python 3.9.7
and juypter
I need help with the async part of it I find it exceedingly difficult
somehow the errors arent even in the lines of code I had written.

Comment: This code won't run properly on any platform.  At the very least, you need to precede every call to `asyncio.sleep` with the `await` keyword.  Perhaps you won't get an error message but the program won't work correctly.  Try posting the entire traceback, or looking at it carefully.  And I mean the whole thing.  There's a very good chance that a line of your own code is lurking in there, somewhere up the call stack.